# SUM multiple columns within date

Tags: sql, date, sum, intervals

Good day to all, i've to do a query that sums some columns together.

```
$sqlannoprima = "SELECT fascia_prezzo,data,giorno,
   SUM (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8) as atot, 
   SUM (g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,gtesi,gg) as gtot,
   SUM (f1,f2,f,3,f4) as ftot, 
   SUM (lt1,lt2,lt3,lt4,ltg) as lttot,
   FROM giorni 
   WHERE STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y')- INTERVAL 1 YEAR BETWEEN 
   STR_TO_DATE('" . $d1 . "', '%d/%m/%Y')- INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
   AND STR_TO_DATE('" . $d2 . "', '%d/%m/%Y')- INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
   GROUP BY giorno 
   ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y')- INTERVAL 1 YEAR";
```

but SQL returns an error when i try to print the results.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   E:\EasyPHP\data\localweb\cdm\stats.php on line 377

And this is at line 377:

```
$risultatoannoprima = $queryannoprima->num_rows;
```

What am i missing?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT fascia_prezzo,data,giorno,SUM(a1) as a1,SUM(a2) as a2,SUM(a3) as a3,SUM(a4) as a4,SUM(a4) as a4,SUM(a5) as a5,SUM(a6) as a6,SUM(a7) as a7,SUM(a8) as a8,(SUM(a1) + SUM(a2) + SUM(a3) + SUM(a4) + SUM(a5) + SUM(a6) + SUM(a7) + SUM(a8)) as atot FROM giorni
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('" . $d1 . "', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('" . $d2 . "', '%d/%m/%Y')
GROUP BY fascia_prezzo,data,giorno
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the last `,` after `lttot` in your sql
Also,you had better use `(INTERVAL 1 YEAR)` instead of `INTERVAL 1 YEAR` directly

```
  $sqlannoprima = "SELECT fascia_prezzo,data,giorno,
   SUM (a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8) as atot, 
   SUM (g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5 + g6 + gtesi + gg) as gtot,
   SUM (f1 + f2 +f3 + f4) as ftot, 
   SUM (lt1 + lt2 + lt3 + lt4 + ltg) as lttot
   FROM giorni 
   WHERE STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y')- (INTERVAL 1 YEAR) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('" . $d1 . "', '%d/%m/%Y')- (INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND STR_TO_DATE('" . $d2 . "', '%d/%m/%Y')- (INTERVAL 1 YEAR) GROUP BY giorno 
   ORDER BY (STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y')- (INTERVAL 1 YEAR))";
```

Comment: I did like you said but nothing changed, line 377 error

Comment: @FrancescoElba add the error message to your original question

Comment: @GordonLinoff I point out one error of it and if you feel comfort about my answer,you can downvote it

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\EasyPHP\data\localweb\cdm\stats.php on line 377 that's the error i get

Comment: @FrancescoElba I told you just now,**add it to your original question**

Comment: @lucumt added yet. Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\EasyPHP\data\localweb\cdm\stats.php on line 377

Comment: @FrancescoElba `Trying to get property of non-object ` you need to search answer for this

Comment: That's why i asked ^^

Answer (score 4):

[`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) is an aggregate function, it sums *rows*, to sum *columns* use `+`, e.g. :

```
(f1 + f2 + f3 + f4)  as ftot
```

or

```
SUM(f1 + f2 + f3 + f4) as ftot
```

if you want to sum on rows and columns

Comment: SUM (a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6a7+a8) as atot, 
   SUM (g1+g2+g3+g4+g5+g6+gtesi+gg) as gtot,
   SUM (f1 + f2 +f3 +f4) as ftot, SUM (lt1+lt2+lt3+lt4+ltg) as lttot

same error